# Edit value of variable in unloaded script

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to edit a variable's value (the variable belongs to an unloaded javascript). In one page I have a couple of buttons that, when pressed, take the users to a new page. The contents of that page are supposed to vary depending on what button is pressed and each button has a corresponding variable value. In my case, that variable value is a string pointing to a file with information (I don't know if that is relevant, heh).

So what I want is basically a way to, with a button click send the user to a new page (currently done with `window.location.href = "<document>";` and edit a variable in a script that is loaded when `<document>` is loaded, depending on which button is pressed.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I haven't been able to find any similar questions so far, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does "unloaded javascript" mean?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. What I mean is that the script is loaded when another page is opened. Therefore it is not loaded (or active) when the current page is open. Hope that makes more sense :)

Comment: Basically, you want to load a new page, and pass some data from the old one to the new one, right? As the answers say there is no direct way to do this, but I would use something like local storage instead of the hash.

Comment: By local storage you mean cookies, right? I don't have any experience with that but you are probably right. As of now I just need a quick solution though, so I will settle with the hash. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Cookies is the old way. Now you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that the way you want. If you don't control `<document>` its not possible for you to control or execute script on that page.

This is a security feature.

If you control `<document>` you can transmit data with the `hash`:

```
document.location.href = '<document>#buttonname';
```

And then consume it in `<document>`:

```
var myVar = document.location.hash; // will be '#buttonname'
```

Relevant is to use the `#` for a part of the URL that will not be sent to the Server.

Comment: Wow that was quick, thanks! That just might be exactly what I am looking for, I will give it a try and update you as soon as I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

So the essence of what I think you're asking is "how do I tell page 2 which button was pressed on page 1".

There are several ways you could do this but I would strongly advise against doing it the way you are suggesting. Reason being, the amount of hackery necessary to do what you're suggesting is scary.

Two ideas:

1. Add a query parameter to the request for the 2nd page telling it which button was pressed.
2. Write the value for which button was pressed to a cookie and read it on the 2nd page.

I can give you some code samples if you're not sure what I mean.